# Rewrite wordpress preview URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do the following rewrite:

```
mydomain.com/?p=706&preview=true to
mydomain.com/index.php?p=706&preview=true
```

using `RewriteRule ^/?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true$ /index\.php [QSA,L]`

However it does not redirect, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]+)&preview=true
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
```

QSA means "append query string from request to substituted URL"

Answer (score -1):

Remove `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true$ /index\.php [QSA,L]
            ^^^
```

so...

```
RewriteRule ^?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true$ /index\.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the line you wrote results in internal server error (500). Got any idea why?

Comment: Is it that ? is a regexp symbol, so it should be escaped to \?